# Distance between two markers

Tags: distance, augmented-reality, markers

I am working on an AR project using Metaio SDK, I'm facing a problem calculating distance between two markers when I point the camera to them, what I'm trying to do is to display a 3d model on each marker while there is a specific distance between them, let's say (10 cm), but when I decrease the distance to 5 for example, I should be able to display another 3d model. I used many methods to achieve that which was always ended in calculating distance between the phone and the target.

```
float distance = FloatMath.sqrt(pos2.getX() * pos2.getY() + pos1.getX()
                * pos1.getY());
float threshold = 50;

        int id1 = 1;
        int id2 = 2;

        boolean successful = metaioSDK.getCosRelation(id1, id2, pose2);

        if (metaioSDK != null) {

            if (pose1.getQuality() > 0 && pose2.getQuality() > 0
                    && distance < threshold) {
                if (successful) {
                    successful = false;
                    mModel1.setVisible(false);
                    mModel2.setVisible(false);
                    mModel3.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    successful = true;
                    mModel3.setVisible(false);
                    mModel1.setVisible(true);
                    mModel2.setVisible(true);

                }
            }
```

any suggestion on how the distance between markers can be determined? 
Thanks